# Copy file to several multiple folders - Batch files

Tags: file, batch-file, copy, directory

How can I copy file to multiple folders using batch files.
I success to copy one file to one folder.

Regards,
Ramzy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this? Seriously, just add a line for each folder.

```
copy C:\file.txt C:\dir1\
copy C:\file.txt C:\dir2\
copy C:\file.txt C:\dir3\
copy C:\file.txt C:\dir4\
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, this is an old thread, but still, i spotted some code that definitely needs an improvement!

Here is a much better movement code!

copy C:\Folder file is in *(Here you can specify certain extension/keyword) C:\destination\
move /-y "SOURCE FOLDER AND DRIVE*(specific keyword/extension)*" "DEST FOLDER AND DRIVE"

That way you dont have to write endless lines of code!

-Logan

Comment: This is just wrong. The question is asking how to copy a single file to multiple folders. Mentioning a source wildcard is irrelevant, and a destination wildcard wouldn't do what is being requested.

Comment: @Andrew Medico Yes, but he could copy to multiple